# Symfony Multiple Repository calls

Tags: php, symfony

I'm pretty new to Symfony (2.0, using this because this is what I have to). I've been basing loads of my code based on past codes.

I was a CodeIgniter developer, and I noticed something rather redundant in the coding style I'm using at the moment.

In CI, every controller has a constructor method where you can declare class level variables. Example:

```
public function _contruct()
{
    $this->load->model('myModel');
}
```

In Symfony however, I have to repeat

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository();
```

and other related repository calls in almost every function.

I'm quite sure there's a better way of doing this, which I'm not aware. So the question is, what is the common standard of initiating models/repositories? Or is it a common practice to repeat those lines over and over again in every function?

Answer (score 0):

it's fine as you're doing it! It's normal you have to get the repository in each action you need to use it. alternatively you can implement [a filter](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters) to get the repository before each action and save it into a class-member.

Comment: so basically, there's no constructor?

Comment: ofc it's possible to override the constructor, but be sure to keep the method signature if it exists in a parent class and call the respective parent method. but the clean way is to use a filter. also it could be a possible problem that when the constructor is executed not all resources may be available to do what you want.